# clear a variable after click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code, and I haven't been able to clear one variable that is causing a bug on my website.

The following code blocks and unblocks a user. So in the If statement checks if the user is blocked or not. So it's always 0 or 1. The thing is that after the page loads the first time the value inside the if statement stays the same, I have to refresh the page so that the value can change.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
$('#confirmBlockUser<?php echo $otherConversation->getId(); ?>').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (<?php echo $otherConversation->isUserBlocked($conUser->getId(), UserSession::getUserId()); ?>) {
        $.post( "/conversation/unblock", { usrId: '<?php echo $conUser->getId(); ?>' })
            .done(function (data) {
                $( ".<?php echo $otherConversation->getId().'-con' ?> span.blocked").hide();
        });

     } else {

        $.post( "/conversation/block", { usrId: '<?php echo $conUser->getId(); ?>' })
             .done(function (data) {
                 $( ".<?php echo $otherConversation->getId().'-con' ?> span.blocked").show();
             });

      }
 });
```

Comment: `$.show` accepts a second boolean argument, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

You add the value with a php output, therefor it stays the same after the page is send from the server. PHP is serverside!

You need JavaScript to achieve this.

So maybe:

```
var blocked = <?php echo $otherConversation->isUserBlocked($conUser->getId(), UserSession::getUserId()); ?>;
...
if (blocked) {
  ...
  // unblock in ajax success function or on another condition
  blocked = false;
} else {
  ...
  // block again, because some condition is met
  blocked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the test for your 'if' statement from php which will only change on page load or by doing an AJAX call.  You'll need to set that php variable via AJAX into a javascript variable and then test that variable in your function.

```
$('#confirmBlockUser<?php echo $otherConversation->getId(); ?>').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$.post('MYBLOCKEDTEST.php',function(RETURN){
    var blocked = RETURN;
    if (<?php echo $otherConversation->isUserBlocked($conUser->getId(), UserSession::getUserId()); ?>) {
    $.post( "/conversation/unblock", { usrId: '<?php echo $conUser->getId(); ?>' })
        .done(function (data) {
            $( ".<?php echo $otherConversation->getId().'-con' ?> span.blocked").hide();
    });

    } else {

    $.post( "/conversation/block", { usrId: '<?php echo $conUser->getId(); ?>' })
         .done(function (data) {
             $( ".<?php echo $otherConversation->getId().'-con' ?> span.blocked").show();
         });

  }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, yeah totally stupid, you guys are right, this will never work. I have to refresh the page -_-

So I did, at the end of the js I added a reload.

```
$('#confirmBlockUser<?php echo $otherConversation->getId(); ?>').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (<?php echo $otherConversation->isUserBlocked($conUser->getId(), UserSession::getUserId()); ?>) {
    $.post( "/conversation/unblock", { usrId: '<?php echo $conUser->getId(); ?>' })
        .done(function (data) {
            $( ".<?php echo $otherConversation->getId().'-con' ?> span.blocked").hide();
    });

 } else {

    $.post( "/conversation/block", { usrId: '<?php echo $conUser->getId(); ?>' })
         .done(function (data) {
             $( ".<?php echo $otherConversation->getId().'-con' ?> span.blocked").show();
         });

  }

location.reload();
```

});